# How to fix timestamp java + firestore problems?

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

i'm creating an chat app depending on firestore and java android
,sorting the chat by timestamp depending on https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/Timestamp

but sorting is every time depends on device time even if the time on device is wrong,this disappoint me,please help!!

---

my code for upload timestamp:

```
Timestamp dd= Timestamp.now();
long tt=dd.getSeconds();
        hashMap.put("ServerTimes",tt);
```

my code for download timestamp:

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MessageAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

Chat chat = mChat.get(position);
       long date = (long) chat.getServerTimes();

        Date date3 = new Date ();
        date3.setTime(date*1000);


        SimpleDateFormat format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy EEE");
        SimpleDateFormat format2 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm:s a");

        String dateDisplay1 = format1.format(date3);
        String dateDisplay2 = format2.format(date3);
String DateTime= dateDisplay1+" -- "+dateDisplay2;
```

My code for sorting:

```
  private void readMessages(final String myEmail, final String OtherUserEmail, final String imageUrl) {
            final List<Chat> mChat = new ArrayList<>();
    referenceContent.orderBy("ServerTimes", Query.Direction.ASCENDING) .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
................
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to rely on the client-side timestamp, you can tell Firestore to [write a server-side timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#server_timestamp). From that documentation link:

> ```
> // Update the timestamp field with the value from the server
> Map<String,Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
> updates.put("timestamp", FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
>
> docRef.update(updates).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
>   ...
> ```

Comment: it saves like this in the firestore July 21, 2019 at 12:37:54 AM U   so i cant sort the chat by this value

Comment: The code I shared saves a date value in the database. Those can be sorted chronologically, as shown in this documentation on data types: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types#data_types. If that doesn't work for you, create a new question where you show the minimal code that reproduces the problem. This question (at least as I interpreted it) was mostly about how to prevent client-side dates (since those are inherently unreliable), which is what my answer shows.

Comment: thank you finally now i succeeded in ordering chats by time stamp by the last step :  referenceContent.orderBy("timestampTest", Query.Direction.ASCENDING)